# Can I use a Firefox bookmark keyword for this search?

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks, javascript

I use http://redirectdetective.com/ a lot, and I love keyword searches. I'd love to combine the two, but it doesn't seem to work; the bookmark destination shows as this: 
`javascript:xmlhttpPost("/linkdetect.px")?word=%s`

Just in case, I tried setting the destination to `http://redirectdetective.com/linkdetect.px?word=%s` and a couple variations, but it just leads to a totally blank page.

Is there a magic URL that will make this work, or does the way the search function is designed prevent it from being used this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated the implementation of linkdetect.px and it looks like the endpoint will only return data when you pass in a referrer header i.e. they are checking that you are calling it from their own website. It's not possible to spoof a referrer from a bookmark, so I'm afraid you're not going to find an easy solution.

The best you can do is to perhaps make your bookmark point to something like `http://redirectdetective.com/?customsearch=%s` and then write a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script that will find the 'customsearch' parameter, autofill it into the text field and then submit the form for you. Basically, you write your own JavaScript that fixes the lack of functionality.